# A very positive offset relative to EBP

Tags: assembly, otool

I have a `i386` binary and have not an opportunity to execute it. The `otool -tv` says:

some funciton or method:

```
0001a1e0    pushl   %ebp            ; just prolog
0001a1e1    movl    %esp,%ebp       ; save old ESP
0001a1e3    pushl   %edi            ; save EDI, ESI, EBX
0001a1e4    pushl   %esi            ;
0001a1e5    pushl   %ebx            ;
0001a1e6    subl    $0x4c,%esp      ; allocate 0x4c bytes for local puproses
...                                 ; etc
```

The instruction somewhere below

```
0001a20e    leal    0xe0(%ebp),%eax ; load an address into EAX
```

is disappointed me! Where the `0xe0(%ebp)` points to? I think this is not a local variable because of positive offset. I can see such access among all the `otool` output. How to interpreter it?

Comment: Even though it's being displayed as a (one byte) usigned number, it's a fair guess the `e0` is being used as a signed number -- and as a signed number, `e0` will be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a reference to a stack address, but your asm is misleading (this is why I don't like AT&T syntax), if you convert `leal 0xe0(%ebp),%eax` to a byte sequence, you'll get `8D45 E0`, which is the same as `LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-20]`.

Its either creating a pointer to a local stack buffer (created by the `SUB ESP`), or creating a pointer to the 7th function param, but without seeing the full code, my bets are on the former.

Comment: I guess its accessing the local variable because the access to a passed argument has a positive offset, like `[EBP+8]` -- first arg, `[EBP+C]` -- the second arg, `[EBP+10]` -- third etc.

Comment: @IvanTeterevkov: it could be creating a pointer to the 7th arg, or a pointer to a stack buffer, bit hard to tell without seeing the full code. I fixed up the answer to be less ambiguous though